# badge suggestion: spread out reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation, badges, badge-request

Let me start with a story:

I was looking at a question somewhere or other on stackoverflow, and I saw one of the answers had 18 upvotes. It was a very good answer. A little habit of mine, I looked at the answerer's reputation. It was 189. Thinking it was weird, as most users with that quality answers have thousands of reputation points, I went to his/her profile page. That was his/her only question or answer. When I had 189 reputation, I had dozens of answers. Even now, with more than 1000 reputation, none of my answers have more than 5 upvotes. None of my questions have more than 2. I think there should be a badge for having a lot of questions instead of just being lucky enough to have an answer that gets a lot of upvotes. I don't have an idea of a name, but feel free to give suggestions in the comments

Comment: So reward people who provide a lot of mediocre posts? I'd prefer to focus on quality, not quantity. Plenty of sites out there already have the quantity part nailed down. We don't want to become one of those.

Comment: `I think there should be a badge for having a lot of questions instead of just being lucky enough to have an answer that gets a lot of upvotes`  Call it "I'm Average!"?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is attracting *quite* so much negative energy. It's not that bad of an idea as soon as you add some checks to eliminate any incentives for post noise.  You asked for suggestions - here's one: Add minimum quality checks:  A bronze badge for having 5 answers with a minimum score of 1, a silver for having 25 with a minimum score of 2, and a gold for having a 100 with a minimum score of 5.  (I didn't test ANY of those numbers - it's just an example.)

Answer (score 8):

This would mean someone could get a badge just for asking dozens of crap questions and doing no research at all, which isn't behaviour that should be encouraged.

Au contraire, generally people should try to do their own research and come to a Stack Exchange site when they can't find the answer. Then, when they do, hopefully they'll be asking a pretty good question that's stimulating and can receive great answers.

When they do that, surprisingly enough they'll get badges and reputation for it, and so will the people providing great answers! *Those* are the badges we need - and have. Ones for lots-o-questions and lots-o-answers aren't.

Comment: then there could be something like the answers/questions need to have a certain amount of votes to be counted?

Comment: If we set it at 10, you'd be getting _Nice Answer_ badges anyway, and it'd be a badge for having lots of badges. If it's set at, say, 5, we're still just rewarding asking a lot of mediocre questions.

Comment: Mind you, we do have badges for having [accumulated a high score in a tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze).

Comment: then why don't we just have accepted answers instead of a vote count?

Comment: @Markasoftware That's a possible good badge! We do have Tenacious and Unsung hero for users with many zero-scoring accepted answers, but that isn't slightly-scored accepted answers.

Answer (score 5):

That's a terrible idea. Badges are for rewarding good behavior. Your proposed badge does not do that. It is better to have a few excellent posts than a ton of mediocre ones.

Comment: It would encourage people to be more active in the site.

Comment: There is already plenty of encouragement to that nature, isn't there?

Comment: @Markasoftware More activity is great but never at the cost of quality

Answer (score -2):

Excellent suggestion.  Actually this has already been thought of and implemented.

First you have the Unsung hero and Tenacious badges

[image]
[image]

Next you've got the by-category tag badges,

[image]

All of these reward "spread-out" reputation, precisely in the manner you've described.

Comment: Hi downvoter!  Feel free to explain the reason for your downvote.

Comment: These _aren't_ already-implemented versions of what's being requested, which is a badge for having a lot of low-rep _questions_. We don't have a badge for lots of low-rep answers, either: Unsung Hero is for when you've provided a lot of helpful (accepted!) answers that haven't received community acknowledgement. The tag badges are for displaying expertise in _a single tag_. Both of those have constraints beyond "lots of answers".

Comment: Actually, I need to correct myself: the request isn't even for "lots of low-rep questions", it's just for "lots of questions" - regardless of any other factor. We _definitely_ don't have a badger that is simply "lots of questions" or "lots of answers", regardless of scores or anything else.

Comment: Well, he said "I had dozens of answers. Even now, with more than 1000 reputation, none of my answers have more than 5 upvotes" .. later he says "I think there should be a badge for having a lot of _questions_" ... but then "instead of __just being lucky enough to have an answer that gets a lot of upvotes__". Rather than take the question literally, I'm saying there are badges for your _dozens of answers_ that don't get that many upvotes.

Comment: Ok, but we don't have a badge that specifically rewards lots of questions/answers, low-scoring or not. We have ones that might incidentally reward that behaviour, if that behaviour happens to fit within _other good constraints_ (the answers are accepted, or are a continuous demonstration of expertise or experience on a particular topic).